# Präposition "an": Dativ oder Akkusativ?

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case, dative, accusative

Es gibt eine Frage in meinem Buch.

> Lesen Sie. Nehmen Sie in einem Brief an die Zeitung Stellung.

Soll es nicht

> Lesen Sie. Nehmen Sie in einem Brief an **der** Zeitung Stellung.

sein ?

Comment: Why do you think "an der" would be correct in this case?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nein. Die Präposition **[an](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/an_Praeposition)** steht je nach Verwendung [entweder mit Dativ oder mit Akkusativ](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Praeposition/Kasus/2Kasus.html). Als Grundregel gilt bei solchen "Wechselpräpositionen":

- Antwortet die Phrase auf die Frage "wo?" (Ortsangabe - statisch), so verwendet man Dativ;
- Geht es um die Angabe einer Richtung ("wohin?"`- dynamisch), verwendet man Akkusativ.

Im Beispiel geht es darum, dass man einen (fiktiven) Brief an einen bestimmten Adressaten (eine Zeitung) richtet, nicht aber darum, "wo" man das tut. Es geht also um die "Richtung" der Aktivität. Damit ***muss*** des Beispiel den Akkusativ verwenden.